# How to reveal DMS SQL query logging with binding values?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, dms

I'm trying get logs created by DMS.
I read DMS documents, and successfully captured DMS's SQL logging like following:

```
2017-02-17T00:58:29 [TARGET_APPLY ]D: Construct statement execute internal: 'UPDATE `some_schema`.`typical_usr_master` SET `id`=? WHERE `id`=? AND `start_dt`=? ''(ar_odbc_stmt.c:3323)
```

However this log doesn't have original binding values, for example `id` or `start_dt`.
If they are revealed, values would be like `id` = "00000001", `start_dt` = "2017-02-17".

Do we have any chance to see such bind values on DMS logging ?
Currently, I changed all logging level to DEBUG, but only ERROR logging shows such binding values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from AWS support.

[How to reveal DMS SQL query logging with binding values ?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=249511)

```
Unfortunately, we do not expose bind values in logs because of security concerns.
Normally, we recommend customers to look at their target to get the actual data 
values we migrated.
```

I'm happy if there was a way to check data integrity.